# How to escape single and plural i18n text strings?

Tags: translation, localization

I've come across the `esc_html_e()` and `esc_attr_e()` functions which allow me to escape translated text strings. I'm now using these instead of `_e()` where appropriate.

The `_n()` function allows for both single and plural forms to be translated. I don't think there's an `esc_attr_n()` function in WordPress. How can I escape the translated text in this case? Here's my current use of the `_n()` function:

```
printf(
    _n(
        '1 item',
        '%d items',
        $count,
        'textdomain'
    ),
    number_format_i18n( $count )
);
```

Ref https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`esc_html_e()` and `esc_attr_e()` are merely wrapper functions for `_` to save a little bit of typing and help with readability. You're right, there isn't one for `_n`, so you'll just need to do the "wrapping" yourself:

```
printf(
    esc_attr(
        _n(
            '%s item',
            '%s items',
            $count,
            'textdomain'
        )
    ),
    number_format_i18n( $count )
);
```

Comment: just wanted to point out I think `printf()` should have 2 params but I can see what you mean by your answer :)

Comment: Yeah my argument nesting was wrong, fixed.

Comment: also `%d` should be `%s` because `number_format_i18n()` returns a string. But that's my fault and kind of irrelevant to the question :)